# Prove that $e$ is the root of the equation $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t+x)\sqrt{4t+(x+1)^2}}=\frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, transcendental-equations

It seems numerically that $e$ is the only real root of the equation:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t+x)\sqrt{4t+(x+1)^2}}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Mathematica confirms it at least to the large number of digits:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t+e)\sqrt{4t+(e+1)^2}}=\frac{1}{e-1}=0.5819767068693$$

[image]

I stumbled on this more or less accidentally, so I have two questions:

> How can we prove that $e$ is the only root of this equation?
>
> Can we create some kind of iteration algorithm to compute $e$ this way?

**Edit**

By the way, the second question can be answered positively, even though numerical integration is involved. We can just use the fixed point iterations:

$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t+x_n)\sqrt{4t+(x_n+1)^2}}$$

$$x_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{I_n}$$

We can take something like $2$ as initial guess.

So, the second question was more about- can we do that without direct numerical integration?

Comment: Just so you know, Wolfram Alpha [confirms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F((t%2Be)*sqrt(4t%2B(e%2B1)%5E2))+from+0+to+infinity) exact equality. To solve the integral, you can try using Euler's substitutions. It will be tedious, but should work.

Comment: Obviously, any real root must be $> 1$. Write your equation with $y \equiv {1 \over x}$ such that $0 < y< 1$. Then, you can use the *Bisection Method* for $y$ in $\left(0,1\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a primitive of the integral
$$
\int\frac{dt}{(t+x)\sqrt{4t+(x+1)^2}}=\frac{\log \left(\sqrt{4 t+(x+1)^2}-x+1\right)-\log \left(-\sqrt{4 t+(x+1)^2}-x+1\right)}{x-1}\ .
$$
Therefore for $x>0$ the definite integral reads
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t+x)\sqrt{4t+(x+1)^2}}=\frac{\log x}{x-1}\ .
$$
Therefore for $x>0$ you only have to solve
$$
\frac{\log x}{x-1}=\frac{1}{x-1}\Rightarrow x=\mathrm{e}\ ,
$$
which is the only solution. For $x<0$, your integral is only defined as a principal value integral.

Comment: I see. It comes back to computing $\log x$. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Can we create some kind of iteration algorithm to compute e this way?

Yes, you can use any root solving algorithm.